# Retrieving core data object from cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, cell

I am saving an object from core data to a cell as listed bellow. The URL is being saved to the cell correctly and working great. My problem is that, when a user taps on a cell, I would like the URL that is saved to that cell to be passed to my `detailedViewController` for use. I have some code that I have tried but the url is nil in the `detailedViewController`. If you have any better way of accomplishing the same thing, that would be fine. The code is listed bellow -

Here is where I save it to the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[PhotoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
FeedEntity *feed = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSData *data = feed.imageData;

self.feedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.thumbImage = self.feedImage;

NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
self.stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.stringForURL = [self.stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];

cell.finalURL = self.finalURL;

return cell;
}
```

Here is where I retrieve the url from the cell and pass it to the detailedViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Code to create detailed view and set properties
    self.detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];

    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    FeedEntity *feed = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
    NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
    NSString *stringURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Here is the string before: %@", stringURL);
    stringURL = [self.stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *urlForDetail = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];

    NSLog(@"Here is the url before it goes to the detailed: %@", urlForDetail);

    self.detailsViewController.finalURL = urlForDetail;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Save the video (in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:):

```
self.videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
self.urlForSave = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

//Look at YES
[videoData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[self saveImageAndVideo];
```

Here is SaveVideoAndPhoto:

```
- (void)saveImageAndVideo {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    FeedEntity *feedEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FeedEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.thumbImage, 0.8f);
    self.photoData = imageData;

    NSString *stringForSave = [self.urlForSave absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"URL before save: %@", stringForSave);

    //NSData * stringData = [stringForSave dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [feedEntity setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
    [feedEntity setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
    [feedEntity setValue: stringForSave forKey:@"urlString"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL's are being saved");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your log statements print out?

Comment: Also, in what file is this code: self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];

Comment: The NSLogs where I push the view controllers just state what I said in the log and where it is supposed to print the url, nothing appears. For example `NSLog(@"Here is the url before it goes to the detailed: %@", urlForDetail);` would print `"Here is the url before it goes to the detailed: ` @Mike

Comment: Also `self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];` is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` along with the rest of the code in the block titled "Here is where I save it to the cell:" @Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];
```

You are setting the URL as a property of SELF, which in this case is your viewController. You want to set it on the CELL. Change all that code when you create the cell from self.whatever to cell.whatever if you want to save them as properties of the cell. It might help you if you did some reading up on scope in objective-c.

Also, on a side note, there are a few things you are doing that are unnecessary. Firstly is this:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

You don't need to create an indexPath object inside this function, because you are already provided it by the function itself with the variable indexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Secondly, inside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath, if you want to get the url, you should be doing something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // deselect the row if you want the cell to fade out automatically after tapping
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // get a reference to the cell that the user tapped
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // get the url from the cell, assuming your cell has a property called finalURL on it that you set some value
    // to originally when it was created
    NSURL *url = cell.finalURL;

    // do something with that URL here...
}
```

Keep in mind this is slightly unorthodox. You really should get the information from your tableView's datasource. If you have an array of objects that you are using to populate your tableView, it's probably a better idea to simply get the object itself from our array with the given indexPath rather than save the information on the cell as a property and access it that way. I would highly suggest watching some tutorial videos or do some reading up, preferably in the iOS docs themselves, to try to learn best practices for UITableViews.

Comment: So in the cell, I am saving the url to the cell as added above.(the line was bellow all of the stuff I was adding and forgot to include it)

Comment: And also, I'm open to getting it from the tableView's dataSource. I just saw something like this in a tutorial and tried it. If you know how to get the info from the dataSource or know of any good tutorials that would be great. I wasn't set on doing this way and and happy to find a better way to do this. I'm very new to core data and objective c in general.

Comment: One more thing, this was also what I was thinking of doing, but couldn't think of how to do it! (sorry about all the comments)

Comment: So for `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` If in cellForRowAtIndexPath I am creating cell's with `PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];` Should I change anything with `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: So the URL is being being retrieved and sent to the detailedViewController but for some reason, it is the same url for every cell. It should give the corresponding url for the thumbnail in the cell. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Seems you must be saving the same URL to every cell. Show the complete code you are using for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Ok, I added the whole cellForRowAtIndexPath above

Comment: So your data source is the fetchedResultsController? It seems like this would work, assuming your data source contains unique objects. My guess is your data source is filled with objects with the same URL.  The way you could determine is this by adding the following code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method -> NSLog(@"%@", feed.URLstring). Add that after the line "FeedEntity *feed = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];"

Comment: feed.URLstring is binary data, a would the nslog still work and b should I change that so that it is a string not binary data

Comment: So it looks like every time it saves another video, it creates the video to the same URL. So when I create the first video it has one url, but then when I create the second video, the second video has the same url as the first one.

Comment: Where do you "create the video"? If that's in separate code looking at that would help too.

Comment: In what file is self.videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];?

Comment: It's in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo which is in the same view controller as the table

Comment: Once again this is a scope issue, you are saving the URL on SELF, which is the view controller. Any time you reference self from a file, you are referencing that specific file's property, which in this case is the viewController, so this doesn't show how you are saving the URL data to your dataSource array/objects. What's inside the saveImageAndVideo function?

Comment: Here, added the SaveVideoAndPhoto

Comment: Just a couple comments - like I mentioned before saving a bunch of random values on "self" just to access them later for use on your core data objects is unorthodox as well as very hard to follow the code. Any properties you want to save should be saved as properties of those specific objects, and if you want to pass them into a function you pass them directly as parameters of the function, like - (void)saveImage:(NSData *)imageData {}. I see you have some log statements throughout the code, thats good - when you run the code and save some objects and load the table, what does the log say?

Comment: So every object I add, URL Before save: is the same url

Comment: Ok, if my answers helped your issue accepting my response as the correct one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh sorry, meant to do that when I commented. Done now